# Commands for successful domain controller replication on Ubuntu / Samba4 / Zentyal

Tags: ubuntu, samba, active-directory, samba4, zentyal-linux

I have a Primary Domain Controller (PDC) and an Additional Domain Controller (ADC) running on two different machines at two different locations connected via a VPN.  Both are running a version of Ubuntu with Samba4.  I'm having trouble getting changes to replicate from DC to DC, but most of my trouble is only one way.

I have determined that the correct way to initiate a replication from PDC -> ADC is to send the following command FROM THE ADC:

```
sudo net rpc share migrate files sysvol \
    -k --destination=ADCserverName.companyname.local \
    -S PDCserverName.companyname.local --acls \
    -U "companyname\\AdminAccountName"
```

...and this works pretty well.

What is not working is my ADC -> PDC replication.  And furthermore, I am not sure about what command I should issue FROM THE PDC to initiate an ADC -> PDC replication.

Would it be the EXACT SAME COMMAND with simply the `--destination=` and `-S` reversed?

Full disclosure: I'm running the two Domain Controllers on Zentyal Community Edition 3.5.  I have tried getting help from the forum there: https://forum.zentyal.org/index.php?topic=23294.0 but the response so far has been zero.  As I understand it Zentyal is merely a customized version of samba4 running on top of Ubuntu with a nice GUI.  So I thought I might get a generic answer related to samba here.

Comment: Someone edited my post.  The command is much easier to read, so thanks.  I am curious why they edited "I am" to "I'm".  I don't really care, it is just... such an irrelevant detail :)

Answer (score 2):

- Step 1: Verify the Kerberos configuration on the Primary Domain Controller (D/C).

  ```
  $> cat /etc/krb5.conf
  default_realm = yourdomain.com
  dns_lookup_realm = true
  dns_lookup_kdc = true
  ```
- Step 2: Update `/etc/resolv.conf` with the address of your DNS Server (same as your Primary D/C.) Do this on your PDC.

  ```
  $> cat /etc/resolv.conf
  search yourdomain.com
  nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  ```
- Step 3: Update `/etc/resolv.conf` on your secondary D/C to point to your PDC.

  ```
  $> echo "search yourdomain.com" >> /etc/resolv.conf
  $> echo "nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX >> /etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- Step 4: If your SMB version is 4.1, DO NOT RUN THIS COMMAND:

  ```
  $ samba-tool domain join yourdomain.com DC \
      -Uadministrator --realm=yourdomain.com
  ```
- Step 5: If the prior step caused an error, make sure you have the `libattr` and `libacl` packages, then remount your filesytem and update your `/etc/fstabs` for permanence. If that doesn't work, add the `--use-ntvs` parameter to the domain join command.
- Step 6: Check resolution of domain.

  ```
  $> nslookup sdc.yourdomain.com
  Server: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  Address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  ```

*From the PDC^^*

If your SDC is not resolvable, add an entry to the file:
`/usr/local/samba/private/dns/example.com.zone`:

```
    sdc IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

*Restart DNS:*

```
$> service named restart
```

*From the PDC:*

```
$> nslookup sdc.example.com
Server: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX#XX
```

Verify `objectGUID` is resolvable to the new hostname for the SDC.

```
$> ldbsearch -H /usr/local/samba/private/sam.ldb '(invocationid=*)' \
    --cross-ncs object guid

dn: CN=NTDS Settings, CN=TEST, CN=SERVERS, 
    CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration, DC=example.com,DC=com
objectGUID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
# ... Records 2
... SAME STUFF
... objectGUID ''-''-''-''-''-''-''
```

*Update DNS record:*

```
$>samba-tool dns add PDC-IP _msdcs.yourdomain.com $GUID CNAME \
    sdc.yourdomain.com --UAdministrator
```

*Edit zone file to add GUID.*

In file: `/usr/local/samba/private/dns/yourdomain.com.zone`:

```
$GUID. IN CNAME sdc
```

*Restart NAMED*

```
$> service named restart
```

*Now try the command again:*

```
$ host -t NAME $GUID._msdcs.example.com
```

*Update your SDC `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to both itself and the PDC*

```
### /etc/resolv.conf
search yourdomain.com
nameserver $PDC_IP
nameserver $SDC_IP
```

Start samba on the SDC.

Comment: I appreciate moderator feedback. This teaches me how to answer questions more effectively.

Comment: Tyler, this is fantastic information.  However, I *think* most of this is already handled by Zentyal's configuration.  What I want to know is what is the command to *manually* initiate replication from ADC -> PDC (but I believe the command is sent from the PDC).  Then, depending on what errors do or do not show up, I will start trying to hunt down where the problem lies using this wonderful tutorial.

Comment: Basically what I want to know is if this command should work FROM the PDC:

sudo net rpc share migrate files sysvol \
    -k --destination=PDCserverName.companyname.local \
    -S ADCserverName.companyname.local --acls \
    -U "companyname\\AdminAccountName"'

Comment: So, will this command work?

Comment: Looks right to me.